# "Möglichkeiten ausloten" vs. "ausreizen"

Tags: difference

Welche Variante ist gängiger und haben sie überhaupt die gleiche Bedeutung?

> Zweitens müssen wir alle **Möglichkeiten ausloten**,...
>
> Wir empfehlen (...), um die klanglichen **Möglichkeiten** des Audio-Systems voll **ausreizen** zu können.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Ausloten** ist das bedächtige Erkunden unbekannter Grenzen. Man will nicht *auflaufen*, also verwendet man ein Lot, um immer *eine Handbreit Wasser unter dem Kiel* zu haben.

> Bernd lotete die Grenzen seines Gefährts aus.

**Ausreizen** ist hingegen das absichtliche Abschreiten bekannter Grenzen, oft mit dem Ziel, die Grenzüberschreitung in den Bereich des Denkbaren zu rücken.

> Bernd reizte sein Gefährt aus.

Answer (score 7):

**Möglichkeiten ausloten** bedeutet vor allem, *alle* Möglichkeiten erst einmal *zu finden* und *aufzuspüren*, in der Regel mit dem Ziel, dieses Wissen dann zu verwenden.

**Möglichkeiten ausreizen** bedeutet, die bekannten Möglichkeiten bis an die Grenzen *zu nutzen*. Um die Möglichkeiten auszureizen, muss man sie also schon kennen.